# Convert GMT to IST in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

How do I convert GMT to IST in IOS ? I have code which will give me time in GMT. But I want to convert it into the corresponding local time zone and use it in my apps. How can I do this ?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code below convert GMT to IST.

```
NSString *inDateStr = @"2000/01/02 03:04:05";
NSString *s = @"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss";

// about input date(GMT)
NSDateFormatter *inDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
inDateFormatter.dateFormat = s;
inDateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
NSDate *inDate = [inDateFormatter dateFromString:inDateStr];

// about output date(IST)
NSDateFormatter *outDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
outDateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"IST"];
outDateFormatter.dateFormat = s;
NSString *outDateStr = [outDateFormatter stringFromDate:inDate];

// final output
NSLog(@"[in]%@ -> [out]%@", inDateStr, outDateStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[(NSDateFormatter *) setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]]; this will give u the local conversion of the GMT to local time zone.
```

Answer (score 1):

I was used below code to convert GMT to IST.

```
NSTimeZone *zone1=[NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
long second=[zone1 secondsFromGMT]; //offset
NSDate *currentdate=[NSDate date];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMddyyyy hh:mm:ss"]; // format
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:second]];

dateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:currentdate];
NSLog(@"Current date %@",dateStr);
```

It may be helpful.

Thank you